# Unable to create time datatype field through visualforce page

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql, jquery, time

I tried to write a formula and extract time field through date time field. But user needs the time field because of specific requirement.

I tried to create a `Visualforce Page` with `Static Resources` based on [Time field in sfdc](https://developforce.wordpress.com/), but, I am unable to display time field. I got an error like

[image]

My visual force page

```
    <apex:page standardController="Account">
<apex:form >
<apex:stylesheet value="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css"/>
<apex:includeScript value="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.1.js" />
<apex:includeScript value="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js" />

<apex:includeScript value="{!$Resource.timeaddon}"/>
<script>
    j$ = jQuery.noConflict();

    j$(document).ready(function() {
    //laod everytime page loaded
    j$(‘#event_start_time’).timepicker({
    showAnim: "slide"
    })
    });
</script>

<style type="text/css">
.ui-timepicker-div .ui-widget-header { margin-bottom: 8px; }
.ui-timepicker-div dl { text-align: left; }
.ui-timepicker-div dl dt { float: left; clear:left; padding: 0 0 0 5px; }
.ui-timepicker-div dl dd { margin: 0 10px 10px 40%; }
.ui-timepicker-div td { font-size: 90%; }
.ui-tpicker-grid-label { background: none; border: none; margin: 0; padding: 0; }

.ui-timepicker-rtl{ direction: rtl; }
.ui-timepicker-rtl dl { text-align: right; padding: 0 5px 0 0; }
.ui-timepicker-rtl dl dt{ float: right; clear: right; }
.ui-timepicker-rtl dl dd { margin: 0 40% 10px 10px; }
</style>

<apex:inputText value="{!Account.Acc_Alternate_Contact_Fax__c}"  id="event_start_time" />
</apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Thanks @AdrianLarson i am updated my question will you please check once now.

Comment: @Paven, please put JS code into the <script> tag, that it could run.

Comment: OK sorry about updates i am working on other side. Thanks for update i will try to post in related one.@AdrianLarson

Comment: @Pavantej Noticed a few things that might be contributing to your issue...Also note that you can always investigate errors in your browser's Javascript console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few things jump out that will prevent your code from working:

- You're using curly quotes (`‘`) instead of single quotes (`'`)
- You're selecting on a literal id, but [`Visualforce` component ids get prefixed](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/pages_best_practices_accessing_id.htm)

  - Instead use an `ends with` selector: (e.g. `$("[id$='event_start_time']")`)

---

The specific problem you're seeing right now is that you've tried to include a script as literal text.

**Correct**

```
<script>
    j$ = jQuery.noConflict();//Initialize your jquery

    j$(document).ready(function() {
    //laod everytime page loaded
    j$("[id$='event_start_time']").timepicker({
    showAnim: "slide"
    })
    });
<script>
```

**Incorrect**

```
j$ = jQuery.noConflict();//Initialize your jquery

j$(document).ready(function() {
//laod everytime page loaded
j$(‘#event_start_time’).timepicker({
showAnim: "slide"
})
});
```

Comment: Works like charm..........@Adrian Larson